# EF-Core query but value missing, even it show in database

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

here is the simple query code...

```
var order = await _context.ProductOrders
                           .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == orderId.ToInt());
```

This is the entity of ProdictOrders

```
public class ProductOrder
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int MovieTicketEnrollmentId { get; set; }

        public string ProductOrderStatusCode { get; set; }

        public int? InvoiceId { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        public string CreateBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }

        public string UpdateBy { get; set; }

        /**
         * Navigation Property
         */

        public MovieTicketEnrollment MovieTicketEnrollment { get; set; }

        public ProductOrderStatus ProductOrderStatus { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ProductOrderItem> ProductOrderItems { get; set; }

        public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    }
```

This data in the database

[image]

And what I got after executing query command above... what's just happening here?

[image]

> MovieTicketEnrollmentId should equal to 1

Comment: Something doesn't add up. Your CreateDate/CreateBy, Invoice ID are missing as well. Get the _context.Database.ConnectionString and verify this is pointing at the same database you are querying.

Comment: Hmmm.. okay I'll try first

Comment: No, but if you refer to the `Watch` console that one is the object after query. but when we look at the table in DB data is there. However, I'll check the connection first